# In Microsoft's YARP library, what is the difference between a RequestTransform and an HttpTransformer?

Tags: asp.net-core, ms-yarp

I am investigating using [Microsoft Yarp](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/tree/main) as a simple reverse proxy server. I am very confused between two types, [`HttpTransformer`](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/blob/main/src/ReverseProxy/Forwarder/HttpTransformer.cs) and [`RequestTransformer`](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/blob/main/src/ReverseProxy/Transforms/RequestTransform.cs). I just want to take an incoming request and strip off a prefix from the given path and then use my existing service discovery infrastructure to dynamically set the host value of the outbound/proxied request. I am not sure which type I should be using as an extensibility point into my custom logic. The `HttpTransformer` has this signature:

```
ValueTask TransformRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext, HttpRequestMessage proxyRequest, string destinationPrefix, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The `RequestTransformer` has this signature:

```
ValueTask ApplyAsync(RequestTransformContext context)
```

The documentation is pretty good, but I was not able to determine the differences between these two types and when to use which one. Can someone please tell me the difference between these two types?